# Cannot find the AspNetCore Nuget packages for 3.0 (specifically routing)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

While developing a large number of microservices, I would like to standardize the heath check middleware calls into a package for reuse.

But I cannot find a nuget package for this .net standard 2.1 project to use that will allow me access to IEndpointRouteBuilder. (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll)

The version i need appears to be embedded in Microsoft.AspNetCore.App but not available by itself as a nuget package (at least not on nuget.org). Other 3.0 assemblies are needed as standalone nuget packages as well.

Is my answer to create and host my own 3.0 nuget package for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing?

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: they removed it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#update-the-project-file

Comment: @DanielA.White I saw that. I guess I was hoping someone could specify the work around to creating this sort of item. I'd rather not duplicate the health check and other custom code in every webapi. I'd like to wrap our specific implementation in a separate reusable project that I can package and reference. You know, the way .net has worked for years.